# Byte function from define to Objective-C code

Tags: c++, objective-c

As far I've been using such macro:

```
#define setBit(k, o) k |= o
```

However now I'd like to remove some defines from my code and get rid of this. I've thought to transform it this way:

```
inline NSNumber *setBit(NSNumber *number, int bit) {
    long long int value = number.longLongValue;

    return @(value |= bit);
}
```

But ofc this will work wrong if we pass `int` value inside the function. Is there any way to make it compatible with all primitive types like `long long int` `int` `NSUInteger` etc?

Comment: Why did you put `@` in the code? There is no such operator in c++.

Comment: Decide which language you are using. Is it `c`, `c++` or `objective-c`?

Comment: But there is such operator in Objective-C, which is the second tag. I'll modify the title of the question. @ means an NSNumber object, which can be any primitive number value wrapped in object. Writing in Objective-C you also use C and C++. The snippet above is a mix, so I can't tag it just Objective-C.

Comment: OK, but why did you tag question as `c++`?

Comment: @NO_NAME I just wrote it. The snippet is a mix, I can't just tag it as Objective-C, because not all who use Objective-C user C / C++.

Comment: The macro version didn't work with NSNumber.  You'll have to make a choice, or have two methods.  Either support primitives, or NSNumber objects, or have two.  I would suggest primitives simply because setbyte sounds like a function where you'd care about performance.  Also it doesn't appear to be setting bytes, it appears to work on 64 bit chunks.  Also 'setbyte' appears to be a bad name, the function appears to be turning on all set bits...

Comment: @KirkSpaziani Name of the function is different, i've changed it for SOF, but indeed, should rather be setBit over setByte - will edit it. Macro doesn't define the type, so here I've tried also not to connect with types. And exactly that's the question, wether I can do it without setting int or NSInteger as a type.